# Passing Multiple Values in Select Option in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, select

I am having issues passing in two values in my select component and working in React. I am currently passing in the correct id value in the selected options.. however when I am passing to the body in newCapabilities, it is receiving a the id value (agent.agentId) instead of the intended name value (agent.agent). I need to be able to send both of the id value and name value that I am mapping through in agent.

What am I doing wrong here?

**react-component.js**

```
  const handleChangeForm = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [id]: value
    })
  }
      const addCapabilities = async (tableName, body) => {
        const newCapabilities = {
          agent
        }
        response(newCapabilities)
      }

      <form>
          <label>Agent</label>
          <select className='add-cap-select' id='agent' onChange={handleChangeForm}>
            <option value=''>Agent</option>
            {agents.map((agent, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={agent.agentId}>
                {agent.agent}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          </form>
```

Comment: you are sending `value={agent.agentId}` that is wrong , send `agent` instead

Comment: I am getting [object Object] when I do that @AyanMehta

Comment: I used  JSON.stringify in the value but I am getting a  string value of '{"agent":"Ricin toxin","agentId":"8"}' when I need to referenced each individual key @AyanMehta

Comment: try const newCapabilities = {
    agent: agents.find(a => a.agentId == agent)?.name
}

Comment: this returns back as undefined but how can I use this elsewhere? i understand why but the string value being returned from the form is the object string i put above. @iamhuynq

Comment: you can create a variable to store value of selected agen `const selectedAgent = agents.find(a => a.agentId == agent)?.name`

Comment: where would put this variable? @iamhuynq

Comment: in outside, so you can able to use it  in everywhere

Comment: should I put it in the handleChangeForm? it keeps coming back as undefined @iamhuynq

Comment: can you provide codesandbox example, so i can take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246395/discussion-between-kjamp-and-iamhuynq).

Comment: @iamhuynq how would i use const selectedAgent = agents.find(a => a.agentId == agent)?.name to find the {"agent":"Ricin toxin","agentId":"8"} in the form being returned? right now when I use agents.form I am getting this complete stringed object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the selected agent and get the name value

```
const newCapabilities = {
    agent: agents.find(a => a.agentId == form.agent)?.agent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to give multiple values => create an object or send an existing object

```
<form>
    <label>Agent</label>
    <select 
        className='add-cap-select' 
        id='agent' 
        onChange={handleChangeForm}>
        {/* Remember to create an empty object value='{}' */}
        <option value='{}'>---- Agent ----</option>
        {agents.map((agent, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(agent)}>
                {agent.agent}
            </option>
         ))}
    </select>
</form>
```

And in the handleChangeForm function

```
const handleChangeForm = (e) => {
    let agent = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
    setAgentId(agent.agentId);
    setAgentName(agent.agentName);
    etc.....
}
```